# Amazon EC2 metered bandwidth. IP or TCP level?

Tags: tcp, amazon-ec2, ip, traffic-measurement

Assuming I have a long lasting persistent TCP connection from my EC2 instance to a client and I send a single byte every 30 seconds (app level keep-alive).

Is that counted as 1 byte traffic, or are TCP headers or even Ethernet overhead counted in as well (which would significantly change the equation)?

Comment: Almost everyone measures at the IP level. That is, the bytes you are considered to have sent are the bytes in each IP packet you send.

Answer (score 2):

Typically bandwidth is measured at the switch level.  And they measure the size of all your packets.

I would assume that's what Amazon does for EC2.

Comment: so that means Ethernet packet size? will I have sent 1 byte or more per keep-alive?